# Control dual color LED without microcontroller

Tags: led, control, spdt

I have a [latching, SPDT switch with dual color LEDs](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Customer%20Drawing%7F2317570%7FA%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_CD_2317570_A.pdf%7F2317570-9) (the first page of the datasheet), that can either be Red or Blue depending on the polarity of the voltage. I would like them to be one color when the button is in position one, and the other color when the button is in position two.

The purpose of the button is as a manual backup switch for a relay board that is normally controlled over CAT5. The relays are tripped by shorting the board's gnd to the pins of the relays.

My voltage source is 110V wall outlet being stepped down to the 12V that both the relay board and LEDs in the button want.

My pinout for the button is:

C: going to gnd of the relay board

NC: nothing connected

NO: going to the relay pins

I found [this guide](https://www.instructables.com/id/The-RedGreen-LED-Guide/) which I believe demonstrates the principal of what I'm trying to accomplish, but with a momentary SPST button and no extra hardware connected, and the intention to use connected to a microcontroller. I can't use a microcontroller in this project as 
 a) no room in the box for one 
 b) no money in the project budget for one.

My main concern, and reason for not just tinkering around, is that the boards are super sensitive to voltage (I already fried one by accident), and I'm worried about sending extra voltage back down the line to the relay board.

Any and all help/tips/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the Electronics StackExchange. It is not clear from your question what you want to accomplish with the LEDs. What state are you trying to indicate? What is their purpose? What should turn each one on or off? It is also not clear what the connections are. If you edit your question, there is a schematic editor that would allow you to draft a schematic to illustrate your question.

Comment: you made no mention of the LEDs in your question .... we have no idea what you want the lights to indicate

Comment: this is unclear `tripped by shorting the board's gnd to the pins of the relays` ...... which relay pins are being shorted?

Comment: Edited post, LED color should indicate the position of the button. <br> If not clear from the datasheet, the LEDs are embedded in a ring within the button itself.<br><br> All of the relay pins are being shorted, I soldered a piece of bare wire between all of them so a short to one is a short to all.

Comment: Are you sure NC means "not connected" here? In the context of buttons, NC usually means "Normally Closed".

Comment: NC is meant to mean "Normally Closed," but that pin/lug has nothing connected to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your specific restrictions are regarding space, but you should have something active. You can use a couple of gates from an inverter chip like the CD40106B, which can easily accommodate 12V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM72W9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The inverter chosen really depends on the current of the LEDs. If you measure the current to be high, you can use an H-bridge chip or discrete transistors.

Comment: CircuitLab isn't letting me view your schematic, could you expand on what G1 and G2 are, and their purpose?

Comment: G1 and G2 are inverters. Their purpose is to transform a high impedance to a low impedance to drive the LED, and to ensure that one end of the LED is always opposite to the other (so that one of the two LEDs is always on).

Answer (score 0):

here's one way

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxuDSG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

but that won't be full  brightness.

the below will give close to full LED brighness. assuming the LEDs in the switces are designed for 12V drive.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzrnqe.png)</sup>

this final one will give one colour when the relay is operated automatically and the opposite colour when it's operated by the switch. and no light when it's idle.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx9hkR.png)</sup>

Comment: 12V though 100 ohms, though? That's too much current for what should be a low-power circuit.

Comment: yeah, even 560 would be pushing it in 1/4W parts :(

Comment: @Misunderstood I know, but that doesn't help - it doesn't say what the resistors are, nor the forward drop of the LEDs.

Comment: @Reinderien sorry, misunderstanding.

Comment: I'm assuming 3V and 470 ohms  in the switches - so designed for 5 to 12V operation  but could be anything.